# Master window controls in sub-windows

Tags: phpstorm

I'm wondering if it is possible to have all the "Master Window" controls (ex: Bar with "File" "Edit" "View"...) in all windows opened by dragging a tab outside the main window ?

I use to work on multiple workspaces, so I've many windows opened for the same project, and for example if I have a window with a SQL command line in a workspace, when I launch an SQL request, the result is shown in the main window on another workspace, it's not very convenient.

I'm not sure to be understandable, so ask for precisions if not ^^